# Unable to decrypt ssl CA cert elasticsearch Docker

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, ssl, docker-compose

i have CA cert password protected in my docker. How can i supply the password. I can't even go into my docker to set the password of ssl based on reference from

```
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/security-basic-setup.html#generate-certificates
```

where i need do below

```
/bin/elasticsearch-keystore add xpack.security.transport.ssl.keystore.secure_password

./bin/elasticsearch-keystore add 
xpack.security.transport.ssl.truststore.secure_password
```

Exception

```
"Caused by: org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSecurityException: failed to load SSL configuration [xpack.security.transport.ssl]",

"Caused by: org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: failed to initialize SSL TrustManager",

"Caused by: java.io.IOException: keystore password was incorrect",
"Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: failed to decrypt safe contents entry: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption.",

ElasticsearchSecurityException[failed to load SSL configuration [xpack.security.transport.ssl]]; nested: ElasticsearchException[failed to initialize SSL TrustManager]; nested: IOException[keystore password was incorrect]; nested: UnrecoverableKeyException[failed to decrypt safe contents entry: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption.];
Likely root cause: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: failed to decrypt safe contents entry: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption.
```

Comment: Have you looked at the elasticsearch documentation on [using certificates with their docker image](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/configuring-tls-docker.html)?

Comment: yes. i also did a workaround where in elasticsearch.yml i need to add xpack.security.transport.ssl.keystore.password: mypassword. However, the password is visible if osmeone access this file. is there a way to pass from .env

Comment: I'm not all that familiar with elasticsearch, but can you set an environment variable named `xpack.security.transport.ssl.keystore.password`? If that works, you can certainly set that in an environment file when running a container.